# Laravel how to define relationship based on two models or columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have the following:

```
//users table
id
name
email
remeber_token
role_id
```

```
//roles table
id
name
```

```
//products table
id
name
```

```
//product_prices 
role_id
product_id
price
```

The price of the product will vary depending on the user role, how to define the correct relationship so in blade I can do something like:

```
$product->price
```

and that will return the correct price depending on the user and the product?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you say the user role, you refer to the role of the authenticated user.

The easiest approach is to define a HasOne relationship on the product model:

```
class Product
{
    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->where('role_id', auth()->user()->role_id)
    }
}
```

So from the view, you can simply say:

```
// Lets use optional() because there may not be any price for that product and user.
optional($product->price)->price
```

If there are many products involved, then using [sub queries](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries) would make more sense.

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::addSelect(['right_price' => Price::select('price')
            ->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id')
            ->where('role_id', auth()->user()->role_id)
            ->limit(1)
        ])->get()

        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

And then in the view:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <p>{{$product->right_price}}</p>
@endforeach
```

For more info, pls check out [this article](https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries).